# Rust ndarray arithmetic operation unexpected type mismatch

Tags: arrays, rust, arithmetic-expressions

I'm having a problem when trying to perform an arithmetic operation on two `Array1`s of the [ndarray crate](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray).

I have tried to reduce my problem to a the following reprex:

```rust
#[macro_use(array)]
extern crate ndarray;

use ndarray::Array1;

fn main() {
  let a: Array1<i8> = array![1, 2, 3];
  let baz = &a - array![1, 2, 3];
  println!("{:#?}", baz);
}
```

It fails with:

```
  |
8 |   let baz = &a - array![1, 2, 3];
  |                ^ expected struct `ndarray::ArrayBase`, found i8
  |
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#arithmetic-operations) I should be able to subtract two `Array1`s and `array!` creates an `Array1`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the [documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#arithmetic-operations) more carefully:

```
&A @ &A which produces a new Array
B @ A which consumes B, updates it with the result, and returns it
B @ &A which consumes B, updates it with the result, and returns it
C @= &A which performs an arithmetic operation in place
```

There is no `&A @ B` situation for some reason. The second argument cannot be consumed. Either none is, or only the first one. As I don't want `a` to be consumed here, that is why I need to reference the return value of the `array!` macro.

So the solution is:

```
let baz = &a - &array![1, 2, 3];
```

The compiler error is not really helping here though...